# Question about solana programs

Tags: solana-program, account, program, solana-cli, getprogramaccounts

Why is it recommended that solana programs check the validity of any account it reads, but does not modify?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example

Comment: @vikingsteve i dont have a specific example it is a general question